# Corresponding entity references: two way sync

Tags: 8

I have two content types containing a reference to each other. When I update the reference on the node of the first content type, I want the reference on the node of the second content type to be automatically updated. Is this possible?

I used the CNR module in Drupal 7, but that's no longer supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [CNR](https://www.drupal.org/project/cnr) module page, it has introduced the replacement....

> New development is done in the http://drupal.org/project/cer module. This expands the corresponding node reference functionality to enitities. Please focus all attention on getting a stable release of cer as soon as possible.

It can do the exactly same thing as CNR...

Comment: CER has been there for quite some time. I'm surprised there still no stable D7 release. :(
Is there be a reasonable alternative for Drupal 8 to use instead?

Comment: They just start port it to Drupal 8... I guess it need a least 1 year to make the 1st version... and I don't think there is alternative one :(